# pagenote package

Tags: packages, pagenote

I would like to change the headings of the note chapter (as created by \printnotes) from

**Chapter #chapternumber**
to
**Title of the chapter**

This would be particularly useful for notes in a \chapter* (without #chapternumber)

So far I have :

```
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand\thepagenote{\arabic{pagenote}}
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{%  default setting: "\textsuperscript{#1}}"
    \textsuperscript{\tiny\bfseries\color{black}#1}
}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{% default setting: "{\normalfont #1.} }"
    {\bfseries\color{black}#1} 
}
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}

\let\footnote\pagenote
```

Thanks for suggestions

The working example :

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand\thepagenote{\arabic{pagenote}}
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{%  default setting: "\textsuperscript{#1}}"
    \textsuperscript{\tiny\bfseries\color{black}#1}
}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{% default setting: "{\normalfont #1.} }"
    {\bfseries\color{black}#1} 
}
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
%\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{subhead}
\let\footnote\pagenote

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}

Bla bla\footnote{this is a footnote in the introduction}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Bla bla~\footnote{this is a footnote in chapter "My first chapter“}

\printnotes 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example as explained here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Comment: I think it is something to do with (re)defining `\pagenotesubhead` but I haven't found the right invocation. Perhaps someone else can?

Comment: the \pagenotesubhead does not do the job.... ses my working example. In fact the point is to know where the chapter title is stored (there is \thechapter and \chaptername but I miss something like \chaptertitle)...